# Measure read/write disk utilisation

Tags: linux, io, disk

I want to measure the read disk utilisation and write disk utilisation.
I used **iostat** and **sar** but they give Total utilisation (in field %util) which includes read and write.

[Resutls using **iostat** and **sar** in my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo55A.jpg)

But I want to know how to calculate the percentage/utilisation of only read or write separately.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/) that shows separate read and write numbers.

You can get its source code and modify to produce the numbers you want.

[image: atop]

Comment: Thank for your quick response.     
But I am sorry because I cannot catch your answer. I mean, in my attached figure, how to calculate the read utils and write utlis. In other words, how much percentage of reading and how much percentage of writing.  Thank you very much